# How to safely store google maps api key in public repo for github pages?

Tags: google-maps, jekyll, github-pages, api-key

I've found nice jekyll template:
https://github.com/volny/stylish-portfolio-jekyll

It tries to present a google map and it needs google map api key which it expects to be stored in `_config.yml`:

```
# API settings
google_api_key:
```

It seems not the safest way to store the key as anybody can see it and use.
How to safely store google maps api key in public repo for github pages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is: **You can't**.

By design, the Google Maps Embed API expects you to include the API Key in the URL where you request your map (as you can observe looking at the [source code of the template your mentioned](https://github.com/volny/stylish-portfolio-jekyll/blob/master/_includes/map.html))

That means your API key will be always be visible in the resulting HTML file rendered in the browser.

Only Google can *try* to prevent other people from using your API Key (by checking the URL of the site where the map being served, for example). There's nothing you can do.

[image]

All that Google can do is to *make it harder* for someone to reuse the API key. They cannot really prevent it in a reliable way. It is just the nature of how the web works. People visiting your site will be the ones requesting the maps - so you can't, for example, restrict the IP address of who can call the API unless you know exactly who those users are (which is just not possible if your site is a public website, which is your case).

Comment: why did you ephasize "try"? I'm getting the feeling that sth's wrong with that trying? ...

Comment: @MarianPaździoch I emphasized the _try_ because all that Google can do is to *make it harder* for someone to reuse the API key. They cannot really prevent it in a reliable way. It is just the nature of how the web works. People visiting your site will be the ones requesting the maps - so you can't, for example, restrict the IP address of who can call the API.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's really not a safe way to store an api key in a public repo.

See [Hide secret key in public repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602747/hide-secret-key-in-public-repository) for further discussion.